# Not able to remove/delete cookie

Tags: c#, .net, cookies

I have set cookie using below code.

```
 HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("test");
 cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
 cookie.Values.Add("UserID", UserID);
 cookie.Values.Add("UserName", UserName);
 cookie.Values.Add("IsUserAdmin", IsUserAdmin.ToString());
 HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

And I am using below code to remove/delete cookie.

```
 HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("test");
 cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);
 Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

However I am not able to remove/delete cookie.
Is there any better way to delete cookie?
Please give me some suggestion on it.

Comment: Please show us the response headers in Chrome Developer Tools so we can see whether those changes are being reflected in the HTTP response.

Comment: Are you sure that the code for deleting the cookie is actually being called?

Comment: Are you sure that the code for deleting the cookie is actually being called? - Yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(cookieName);
        cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
        cookie.Values.Add(cookieName, string.Empty);
        HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

This code is working on my side.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
At the time of posting this answer, the OP's posted code showed a `Partner_Portal_Cookie` cookie being deleted. Since then, the posted code has been editted.

---

You are trying to delete your `test` cookie right?
Your code example shows you deleting a `Partner_Portal_Cookie` cookie.

Try something like:

```
if (Request.Cookies["test"] != null)
{
    HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("test");
    myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);
    Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
}
```

The example is from [mdsn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178195.aspx). Essentially we are checking if the cookie exists. If it does, create a new cookie with the **same name** and set the expiration date to the past.

Comment: Yes agree. It was by mistake. The problem still persist. using your trick.

Comment: @PankajDhote Did you see my comment on the original post? It was asking if the delete cookie code was actually being called.

Comment: HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("test");
cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
cookie.Values.Add("test", string.Empty);
HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

Using this code I am able to delete cookie today.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
public static void ClearCookies()
            {
                HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("test");

                cookie.Name = "test";
                cookie.Value = string.Empty;
                cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);

                if (HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.AllKeys.Contains("test"))
                {
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Set(cookie);
                }
                else
                {
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
                }
            }
```

Comment: HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("test");
cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
cookie.Values.Add("test", string.Empty);
HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

Using this code I am able to delete cookie today.